# Problems with stubbing spy'ed object in scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, specs2

I have a pretty complex test where I decided to go with approach of partial stubbing of tested class. in my test I have something like this:

```
val srv = new Service()
val srvSpy = spy(srv)
doReturn(now).when(srvSpy).getRunDateInTimeZone(futureChecklist)
doReturn("boo").when(srvSpy).interpolateChecklistName("name", now)
val returnTuple = (createdChlRev, createdChl)
doReturn(returnTuple).when(srvSpy).create(fChlCreatorId,
        fChlCreatorEmail,
        "username",
        true,
        templateId,
        "boo",
        optDueDate)(connection)

val (chlRev, chl) = srv.createFromFutureChecklist(futureChecklist)(connection)
```

In the code above, the first two stubbed methods working as expected. However, the last one throws an error:

> [error]    Tuple2 cannot be returned by create$default$8() [error]
>   create$default$8() should return JsObject [error]    *** [error]    If
>   you're unsure why you're getting above error read on. [error]    Due
>   to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because: [error]
>   1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests. [error]       Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of
>   concurrency testing. [error]    2. A spy is stubbed using
>   when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - [error]
>   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

I've trying bunch of different approached of stubbing and still getting the same error. At this point I have no idea even where to look.
What am I doing wrong?

Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was my own dumb mistake. I was stubbing the spied class, but calling the original one :(

Thanks,